# How to prevent table being stretched?

Tags: html, css

I want to prevent the table of the searched data being stretched. If there are many data that are searched, the table size is okay, but when there are small data that are being searched, it will display the data in the stretched table height which looks awkward. I need to know how to prevent the table from stretching.:(

Below are the codes.

```
    <style type="text/css">
table{
background-color:#EBEBEB; /*background line table*/
}
th{
    width:150px;
    text-align:left;
    }

    </style>
    </head>

    <style type="text/css">
    table {
      table-layout:fixed;
         width:100%;
         border:0px solid ; 
         height:1px;


             word-wrap:break-word;
            overflow:scroll;
            }
            p   {font-size:9px}

         tbody { height:20em;  overflow:scroll; width:fixed;}
     td { height:auto;}

    </style>

    <body>


    <form method="post" action="searchschoolsthis.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />

    <label><span class="style2">Pilih Kategori:</span>
    <span class="style1">
    <select name="category">
      <option value="negeri">NEGERI</option>
      <option value="daerah">DAERAH</option>
      <option value="kod_sekolah">KOD SEKOLAH</option>
    </select>
     </span></label>

     <span class="style1">
     <span class="style2">Taip Kriteria
     <label>:</label>
     </span>
     <label>
     <input type="text" name="criteria" onKeyUp="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();"/>
     </label>
     <input type="submit" value="Cari" />
                </form>   


                <form action="php_excel_export.php?criteria=<?php echo($_POST['criteria']); ?>" method="post" name="criteria" target="_blank" id="cetak">
                 <input type="submit" name="cetak" id="cetak" value="Cetak" />
                </form>

     </span>


       <table width='100%' color='black' id='header'>

       <thead>
        <tr>
          <td width="40%" scope="col"><div align="center"><span class="style2">Kod Sekolah</span></div></td> 
          <td width="40%" scope="col"><div align="center"><span class="style2">Nama Sekolah</span></div></td> 
          <td width="40%" scope="col"><div align="center"><span class="style2">PTJ</span></div></td> 
          <td width="40%" scope="col"><div align="center"><span class="style2">Server</span></div></td> 
          <td width="40%" scope="col"><div align="center"><span class="style2">PC</span></div></td> 
          <td width="40%" scope="col"><div align="center"><span class="style2">NB</span></div></td> 
          <td width="40%" scope="col"><div align="center"><span class="style2">Mono Laser</span></div></td> 
          <td width="40%" scope="col"><div align="center"><span class="style2">Color Laser</span></div></td> 
          <td width="40%" scope="col"><div align="center"><span class="style2">Dot Matrix</span></div></td> 
          <td width="40%" scope="col"><div align="center"><span class="style2">LCD</span></div></td> 
          <td width="40%" scope="col"><div align="center"><span class="style2">Set LAN</span></div></td> 
          <td width="40%" scope="col"><div align="center"><span class="style2">Jumlah Kos</span></div></td> 
          <td width="40%" scope="col"><div align="center"><span class="style2">Dibayar</span></div></td> 
          <td width="50%" scope="col"><div align="center"><span class="style2">Tanggungan</span></div></td> 
        </tr>
      </thead>
        </table>


    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['submitted'])){

    include('connect.php');
    $category=$_POST['category'];
    $criteria=$_POST['criteria'];
    $query="SELECT * FROM schools WHERE $category = '$criteria'";
    $result=mysqli_query($dbcon,$query) or die('error getting data');


    echo "<table width='120%' border='2' color='black' id='header'>";


    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)){


    echo"<tr><td>";

    echo $row['kod_sekolah'];

    echo"</td><td>";    

    echo $row['nama_sekolah'];
    echo"</td><td>";

    echo $row['ptj'];
    echo"</td><td>";

    echo $row['server'];
    echo"</td><td>";

    echo $row['pc'];
    echo"</td><td>";

    echo $row['nb'];
    echo"</td><td>";

    echo $row['mono_laser'];
    echo"</td><td>";

    echo $row['color_laser'];
    echo"</td><td>";

    echo $row['dot_matrix'];
    echo"</td><td>";

    echo $row['lcd'];
    echo"</td><td>";

    echo $row['set_lan'];
    echo"</td><td>";

    echo $row['jumlah_kos'];
    echo"</td><td>";

    echo $row['dibayar'];
    echo"</td><td>";

    echo $row['tanggungan'];
    //echo"</td><td  style='text-align:right'>";

    echo"</td></tr>";

    }

    echo "</table>";

    }


    ?>
```

Comment: If this is an HTML/CSS problemn why are you showing us PHP and MySQL code? Please show us the code received and displayed by a browser, not the one executed server side that'll be sent to the browser. It's of no use here.

Answer (score 3):

You could try using the CSS instruction `display: inline-table;` on the table element.

```
table {
  display: inline-table;
  table-layout:fixed;
  border: none; 
  word-wrap:break-word;
  overflow:scroll;
}
```

Maybe you'll have to remove `table-layout:fixed;` and instructions with width on cells

Comment: It worked for the width, but I am trying to fixed the height because every time i search 1 data, the 1 data will be displayed on the table with stretched height which will look awkward. If there are a lot of data, the data will be displayed in a scrolled table which is working. The problem is when I want to search data less than 10 lines. The table height will be stretch to fit the scrolled table.

Answer (score 1):

Cleaned up your code (almost completely re-writing it). The code below  seems to work (guessing at data types/format) with short and long lists if data.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            table {
                background-color:#EBEBEB;
                table-layout:fixed;
            }
            th {
                text-align:center;
                min-width:90px;
            }
            td {
                text-align:center;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="searchschoolsthis.php">
            <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />
            Pilih Kategori:
            <select name="category">
                <option value="negeri">NEGERI</option>
                <option value="daerah">DAERAH</option>
                <option value="kod_sekolah">KOD SEKOLAH</option>
            </select>
            Taip Kriteria:
            <input type="text" name="criteria" onKeyUp="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Cari" />
        </form>   
        <form action="php_excel_export.php?criteria=<?php if(isset($_POST['criteria'])){echo($_POST['criteria']);} ?>" method="post" name="criteria" target="_blank" id="cetak">
            <input type="submit" name="cetak" id="cetak" value="Cetak" />
        </form>
        <table id='header'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Kod Sekolah</th> 
                    <th>Nama Sekolah</th> 
                    <th>PTJ</th> 
                    <th>Server</th> 
                    <th>PC</th> 
                    <th>NB</th> 
                    <th>Mono Laser</th> 
                    <th>Color Laser</th> 
                    <th>Dot Matrix</th> 
                    <th>LCD</th> 
                    <th>Set LAN</th> 
                    <th>Jumlah Kos</th> 
                    <th>Dibayar</th> 
                    <th>Tanggungan</th> 
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submitted'])){
        include('connect.php');
        $category=$_POST['category'];
        $criteria=$_POST['criteria'];
        $query="SELECT * FROM schools WHERE $category = '$criteria'";
        $result=mysqli_query($dbcon,$query) or die('error getting data');

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
            echo"<tr><td>".$row['kod_sekolah'];
            echo"</td><td>".$row['nama_sekolah'];
            echo"</td><td>".$row['ptj'];
            echo"</td><td>".$row['server'];
            echo"</td><td>".$row['pc'];
            echo"</td><td>".$row['nb'];
            echo"</td><td>".$row['mono_laser'];
            echo"</td><td>".$row['color_laser'];
            echo"</td><td>".$row['dot_matrix'];
            echo"</td><td>".$row['lcd'];
            echo"</td><td>".$row['set_lan'];
            echo"</td><td>".$row['jumlah_kos'];
            echo"</td><td>".$row['dibayar'];
            echo"</td><td>".$row['tanggungan'];
            echo"</td></tr>";
        }
    }
?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note: If this doesn't work with your data, you'll need to provide a sample of it for further help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to conform to a set width every time, use css to set an exact pixel value

```
style="width:200px;"
```

Your table header is a little bit messed up.  Your width percentages on the s should not exceed 100% when combined together.

If you want a variable width depending on the browser size, use the css assets "max-width" and "min-width".

Comment: Still not working. Where should I put the style="width:200px;"?
The table height of the searched data still stretch when there are small number of data being displayed :(

Comment: You would only put style="width:200px;" if you were going to go about it with in-line styles.  If this is the case you would do <td style="width:200px;">Contents</td>  You will have to adjust the pixel widths to ones which better suit your layout of course.

Comment: The better option is to not do inline styling.  It would be better to assign separate classes for each column which would then have css widths.

Answer (score -1):

You can use PHP chunk_split() function to keep the longest word to fit in the